# Visual code inspector for QT classes and objects

Tags: qt

To be honest, I think that the QT quick when using widgets is a pretty bad visual tool for front-end developers, It's really hard to find the object you want to edit. I'm working with a big application and there some widgets there were not deleted, I had to create a huge map of all widgets we had, the UI files, and I still need to go to open each file in order to find a button class/object if I want to add some properties on my CSS file. Is there anything that looks like the chrome or firefox inspector, so when you click on the compile file or even on debugging mode on visual studio you can find what objects and classes you are seeing rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Yest, there's an GPL tool named [GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/gammaray/).